# Iterating through a list and assign an ID to the group of elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists called `new_oder_list`. I am iterating through this. I would like to create a sub-batch of `20 unique ids` from these lists. The same `id` may appear in the next list so I am keeping a track of the `ids` in the `order_chk_lst` list. If there is a repetitive id in the list, I would like to skip that element and check the next element. I am assigning a unique ID to each sub-batch(of 20 elements). I have tried the following code but I am not getting more than 20 ids. I have tried the following code. I would really appreciate your feedback. Thank you.

`new_order_list`

```
[5029339601, 5029339775, 5029338374, 5029338219, 5029339927, 5029338917, 5029338917, 5029338219, 5029339601, 5029338905, 5029339320, 5029338282, 5029338374, 5029339109, 5029339320, 5029369758, 5029338282, 5029369758, 5029368075, 5029368652, 5029339941, 5029368652, 5029369810, 5029339584, 5029339584, 5029339775, 5029369810, 5029338531, 5029368003, 5029339536, 5029340252, 5029338531, 5029339137, 5029340252, 5029368003, 5029339137, 5029339536, 5029338531, 5029367966, 5029339109, 5029338390, 5029368075, 5029339576, 5029368083, 5029338209, 5029338417, 5029338905, 5029339576, 5029339941, 5029368075, 5029339895, 5029340051, 5029368075, 5029338390, 5029370218, 5029370218, 5029338209, 5029340051, 5029339895, 5029367966, 5029338417]
[5029370469, 5029368482, 5029370383, 5029340357, 5029340357, 5029370563, 5029370469, 5029340412, 5029339528, 5029370121, 5029370121, 5029370121, 5029368482, 5029368535, 5029370563, 5029339528, 5029370328, 5029368866, 5029369260, 5029369260, 5029369326, 5029370469, 5029338175, 5029338175, 5029368535, 5029368866, 5029368248, 5029340270, 5029339842, 5029339528, 5029340287, 5029338230, 5029368248, 5029368535, 5029368866, 5029340270, 5029339513, 5029369326, 5029368528, 5029340412, 5029339842, 5029338230, 5029370469, 5029370328, 5029369961, 5029340287, 5029370563, 5029370383, 5029340476, 5029340476]
```

`implementation`

```
MAX_ORDER = 20
batch_id = 10000000
sub_batch_id = 10000000


for i, order in enumerate(new_order_list):
    # Increment batch_id if the order reaches every MAX_ORDER

    if order in order_chk_lst:
        # if the id is repeated then go to the next ( I think I am making a mistake here as the value of `i` will change.
        continue

    order_chk_lst.append(order)

    if i % MAX_ORDER == 0:
        batch_id = 1

         
        # assign sub_batch_id for each zone (i == 0 will be the first assign within the batch)              
        # This is my function which will assgn the batch id (I have added this for a reference)
        sub_batch_assign, sub_batch_id = assign_sub_batch(zones, sub_batch_id)


# e.g. sub_batch_assign = {"1A": 10000000, "1B": 10000001, "1D": 10000002}
def assign_sub_batch(zones: list, sub_batch_id: int) -> (dict, int):
    sub_batch_assign = {}
    for zone in zones:
        sub_batch_assign[zone] = sub_batch_id
        sub_batch_id += 1
    return (sub_batch_assign, sub_batch_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want unique items just change `new_oder_list` to a `set`, it will remove all the duplicates. Iterate over the list of lists and use `update` to add the items to `order_chk_lst`

```
order_chk_lst = set()
for lst in new_order_list:
    order_chk_lst.update(lst)
```

You can also change it back to list if you really need it to be list

```
order_chk_lst = list(order_chk_lst)
```

If the order is important you can use the fact that `dict` preserve the order since Python 3.6

```
order_chk_dict = {}
for lst in new_order_list:
    order_chk_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(lst))
order_chk_lst = list(order_chk_dict.keys())
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have a list of lists. The same`id` can appear in the next list as well. That is why I have created a `order_chk_lst`. So if the element is already in the list then I will be going to the next `id`.

Comment: thanks a ton. the `lst` mentioned in your code is not a list actually. It is an element in the list in my case.

Comment: @Sam what do you mean by *element`? it this an object that has list attribute?

Comment: I meant it is one of the `ids` in the list. (e.g.`5029339601`)

Comment: thanks. The order of the list is important. and when we use `set` ,it does not take care of the order. What should I be doing in that case?

Comment: but with the new implementation there will be duplicate `ids`. How can I remove those duplicate `ids` and get the unique `ids` without changing the order of `ids`?

Comment: @Sorry my bad. I checked the wrong results.